# How do I disable DirectDraw and Direct3D acceleration on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, directx

Some old games that I would really like to play run slowly on some graphic drivers when Direct3D acceleration is enabled.

I have tried many suggestions but none seem to work. The only thing  I have not tried is disabling Direct3D acceleration. Is it possible to disable DirectDraw and Direct3D acceleration on my Windows 8 PC?

From [InterAction Studios](http://www.interactionstudios.com/ci2/supportci2.php):

> There are certain bad versions of GeForce drivers that cause this
> problem. This is a problem in the drivers themselves and is
> unfortunately completely outside our control. The recommended way to
> fix this problem is to update your graphics card drivers (go to
> NVIDIA's web site for this).
>
> Alternatively, there is a workaround that
> alleviates or solves the slowdown problem altogether.
>
> Try this: Right-click on your desktop and select "Properties". Go to the
> "Settings" tab and click on "Advanced...". Click on the
> "Troubleshooting" tab and move the slider to the left until it says
> that all DirectDraw and Direct3D accelerations have been disabled
> (around the middle of the range). Finally, click on "OK".
>
> Note that
> this workaround might cause other games on your computer to slow down,
> so you may have to switch back and forth between settings, but it's
> certainly worth a try if you can't obtain an updated graphics driver.

Comment: Do you have real reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: @ChrisF I used this to fix the colors in StarCraft on the old Intel integrated graphics.

Comment: Your problem is less likely DirectDraw and DirectX, and more likely to do with the WDDM 1.2 driver model that's preferred in Windows 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible I did it .(Successfully tested on **Windows 8 RTM**)

**Steps:**

**1.** Disable Aero(Mostly not necessary but do it for now)
[Disable aero](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-aero-on-windows-vista/)

**2.** Download directx 9.0c control panel from [here](http://www.majorgeeks.com/Microsoft_DirectX_Control_Panel_d4017.html)

**3.** Extract and run **"directx.cpl"** as administrator.

**4.** Goto Direct3D and DirectDraw tabs and uncheck "Allow hardware acceleration ".
[image: directx control panel]

**5.** Run dxdiag from Directx tab else from run command and check status
[image: dx status]

Comment: Why is it in high contrast? is it necessary?

Comment: no i have kept it .. its not necessary at all ...

Comment: After doing this, I have the same results.. BUT If I run DxDiag in x64 mode (from the system tab) it shows that Both DirectDraw and Direct3d are enabled....!
Any ideas on how to disable them there?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the good old registry keys?

```
Reg Add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectDraw /V EmulationOnly /T REG_DWORD /D %_Mode% /F
Reg Add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers /V SoftwareOnly /T REG_DWORD /D %_Mode% /F
```

These can be automated as outlined in the following post:

http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/shortcut-batch-file-code-to-disable-direct-draw-acceleration-437584.html

Also, isn't it still in the compatability wizard as "`ForceDirectDrawEmulation`"?